# How to throw exception only once using openmp

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a simple code as below.

```
int a , b;
std::cout << "Enter the value of a and b " << std::endl;
std::cin >> a >> b;
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    try
    {
        if( b == 0 )
        {
            throw std::exception( "Attempt to divide by zero" );
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << ( a / b );
        }
    }
    catch( const std::exception e )
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

As  there are eight threads. The exception is thrown eight times, if the value of b is 0. I also couldn't set the number of threads as 1 inside the try block. I like to use multiple threads but if there is an exception ,it should be thrown only once. I tried with "critical" and "barrier". But it makes no difference. I am using visual studio 2013 ultimate. I am unable to use new features of openmp. Are there some suggestions.

Comment: Is something like this relevant to your particular problem? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521443.aspx

Comment: @RegretBomb It resembles someway, I tried with parallel for and loop it only once, it throws the exception only once, it works for simple code as above, However, I am working with a larger code, The exception may occur in a nested parallel for, so , they will be thrown multiple times again :(

Comment: Using the Concurrency Runtime means that the exception is only thrown once.

Comment: Oh. ok @RegretBomb. Time to change the code again :)

Comment: @High Performance Mark. The above code seems worthless of using openmp. I posted the simple code just to gain some insights, if there is a way. However, the real code is huge and requires multiple threads with what I am actually working. I will try the suggestions by RegretBomb.

Comment: @RegretBomb using concurrency runtime removed the problem of throwing exception multiple times, but it is more slower than a normal program. Any suggestions.

Comment: @Launa, no sorry. Concurrency Runtime has quite a large performance overhead as it's doing quite a bit for you in the background. Consider programming without Exceptions and use an alternative error handling model?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single region with a nowait clause.

Comment: I am not allowed to use many features of openmp with vs 2013 as Section, task, nowait and others

Comment: If you're allowed to use a single region, you can still use that without nowait. It will just make the remaining threads wait.

Comment: Not allowed? I am amused there's a style guide that permits C++ exceptions from OpenMP regions but prohibits nowait :-)